# Different behavior of `sink` during an R session compared to calling R from a shell command

Tags: r

I want to produce a file containing the coverage test results through the `covr` package so that we ca use it in our CI tool. If I run the following commands in an interactive R session I get the expected behavior

```
con <- file("coverage.txt") 
sink(con, append = TRUE) 
sink(con, append = TRUE, type ="message")
covr::package_coverage(function_exclusions = "is_")
sink()
```

Instead if I use in the bash shell

```
Rscript -e "con <- file("coverage.txt"); sink(con, append = TRUE); sink(con, append = TRUE, type = "message"); covr::package_coverage(function_exclusions = "is_"); sink()"
```

or

```
R -e "con <- file("coverage.txt"); sink(con, append = TRUE); sink(con, append = TRUE, type = "message"); covr::package_coverage(function_exclusions = "is_"); sink()"
```

I got the following error

> Error in file(coverage.txt) : object "coverage.txt" not found

Do you have any suggestions to solve this issue?

Comment: That's probably due to the fact that the root directory is not the same in both case. try to specify the full path to the file instead of using the one define by default.

Comment: Can this be because of wrong quoting in the shell? (Looks very much like it with syntax highlighting.)

Comment: You are right, I used only the `"` instaed of mix `"` and `'`.